# Synonym for "Context" or "Situation"

Tags: meaning-in-context, synonyms

I am looking for a word that is a synonym for "context" or "situation" but describes someone's present moment in a more holistic way.  It would be a single word that refers to the entirety of the situation - the location, the surroundings, the feelings, the time, etc.

Any ideas?  A regular Thesaurus wasn't helping.  Thanks!

-------------------------------**EDIT**-----------------------------------

I am specifically looking for a short word, preferably one syllable, but a word that still grasps many aspects of a situation:

- External (environment, surroundings)
- Internal (emotions, sequence of events in one's life, the "aura" surrounding the person & situation)

I know that these limit the synonym possibilities, but that's why a Thesaurus wasn't helping!

I am also open to words that may not have an English origin, or even a hybrid.

Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with 'context'? You need to give us the context to have any idea of why one word or another will work.

Comment: Mitch, you are correct, I did a poor job of explaining what I need.  I'll edit the question to explain more.

Comment: Let me quote the best I have ever seen here by Robusto. Just because you can think up a description doesn't mean there will be a single word it applies to. What's a single word for a left-handed nun who eats pickled herring before chanting vespers at a Lithuanian convent?

Comment: Well said!  There very well may not be a single word for what I describe, but I'll never know unless I ask!

Comment: I've posted an answer, but if you want an informal word in modern usage what about **'place'**, eg. *"He's not in a very good place at the moment."*, meaning something like 'his overall situation is unenviable'.

Comment: Similar to JHCL's suggestion - (their/his/her) **'world'** (as opposed to 'the world') - *eg* "Rob's world was uniformly dull, the one exception being...". This can be used in both senses, as can **'life'** - *eg* "Sarah's life had it's ups and downs..."

Comment: Would you consider using *crux*?  You seem to want a syllable, and it can perhaps be used to mean the point to which events have led.

Comment: Crux is very interesting.  I think that's a great word to capture a component of the situation, but not the entire situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the edited question (single-syllable requirement), I'd simply suggest [**'State'**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/state):

> The particular condition that someone or something is in at a specific time: (-- Oxford Dictionaries Online)

Comment: "State" is not bad at all.  I think it does meet all those conditions.  I may accept this answer, but I'm really looking for something more elegant.  I know that's pretty demanding, but I'm hoping to use this word in a title, so the feelings it evokes is important.  Thanks, good answer!

Answer (score 2):

Consider ***circumstances***.

> circumstances : the way something happens : the specific details of an event

<sup>([Merriam–Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/circumstances))</sup>

Comment: I like this answer as it can refer to the *internal* (eg. state of mind) and *personal* (eg. physical capabilities), as well as the *external* (environmental) situation.

Comment: I did a poor job of explaining exactly what I need.  "Circumstances" is a bit too "technical".  I will explain more in an edit to the question.  Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

[Environment] includes everything around you in a more holistic way as defined in [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/environment):

> the circumstances, objects, or conditions by which one is surrounded

Comment: I did a poor job of explaining exactly what I need.  "Environment" is good for referring to one's surroundings, but not all that I need.  Thanks though!